# Regular expression to match a string having string inside parentheses

Tags: regex

I want a create a regular expression that matches the certain rules.

I found this RE - `/^.*\(.*\).*$/g` but i also wanted to have validation on second string inside parenthesis.

eg-

```
 United Kingdom (English)

 Belgium (Dutch)
```

ie- expression for [string space string inside parenthesis with at least 3 length of inside string.].

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `JavaScript`:

```
const pattern = /^[A-Za-z\s]+\([A-Za-z]{3,}\)$/;
const str1 = 'United Kingdom (English)';
const str2 = 'Belgium (Dutch)';

console.log(pattern.test(str1)); // true
console.log(pattern.test(str2)); // true
```

Explanation of the pattern:

```
^ asserts the start of the string.
[A-Za-z\s]+ matches one or more letters or spaces.
\( matches the opening parenthesis.
[A-Za-z]{3,} matches three or more letters (assumed to be the inside string you mentioned).
\) matches the closing parenthesis.
$ asserts the end of the string.
```

Comment: Thank you sir . your RE was so clean didn't even required the explanation. here's your upvote sir.